# How to load different Kendo UI Slider over default Kendo style

Tags: css, kendo-ui, telerik, slider

I am using the CSS as given below for my Kendo controls in my ASP.net MVC application:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Telerik/styles/kendo.common.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Telerik/styles/kendo.default.css")
```

However I don't want the default styling applied on Kendo Slider control and wish to load a different theme say 'Silver' theme which can be seen in [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/slider/index) demo

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the Other Styles css in below link.

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/tree/master/styles/web

Download and import the css in your project.

After this, using the below function you can acheive the change theme.

```
$(function() {
 changekendoTheme("Silver");
});

 function changekendoTheme(skinName, animate) {
        var doc = document,
            kendoLinks = $("link[href*='kendo.']", doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]),
            commonLink = kendoLinks.filter("[href*='kendo.common']"),
            skinLink = kendoLinks.filter(":not([href*='kendo.common'])"),
            href = location.href,
            skinRegex = /kendo\.\w+(\.min)?\.css/i,
            extension = skinLink.attr("rel") === "stylesheet" ? ".css" : ".less",
            url = commonLink.attr("href").replace(skinRegex, "kendo." + skinName + "$1" + extension),

            url2 = commonLink.attr("href").replace(skinRegex, "kendo.dataviz." + skinName + "$1" + extension);

        exampleElement = $("#example");

        function preloadStylesheet(file, callback) {
            var element = $("<link rel='stylesheet' media='print' href='" + file + "'").appendTo("head");
            setTimeout(function () {
                callback();
                element.remove();
            }, 100);
        }

        function replaceTheme() {
            var oldSkinName = $(doc).data("kendoSkin"),newLink;
            var newLink1 = doc.createElement('link');
            newLink1.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            newLink1.setAttribute("href", url);

            var newLink2 = doc.createElement('link');
            newLink2.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            newLink2.setAttribute("href", url2);

            var head = document.head;

            head.insertBefore(newLink2, skinLink[0]);
            head.insertBefore(newLink1, skinLink[0]);

            skinLink.remove();

            $(doc.documentElement).removeClass("k-" + oldSkinName).addClass("k-" + skinName);
        }

        if (animate) {
            preloadStylesheet(url, replaceTheme);
        } else {
            replaceTheme();
        }
```